# Instagram API media endpoint giving null results

Tags: web-services, rest, instagram, instagram-api

I have a requirement where i need to get all the images tagged at a given location in Instagram.
For this i am trying to use the Instagram API with Media Endpoint as described in the link https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/.

I use the following API URL to get the media information.
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=

But the result is displayed as {"meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}
The result is displayed same for any location co-ordinates.

The access key is valid and i get the result for location endpoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are in Sandbox mode https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

You will only see your photos and your sandbox users in results, try searching for a location that you have posted a photo and only that will show in results, once your app is reviewed and live, all results will show up.

> The behavior of the API when you are in sandbox mode is the same as
>   when your app is live, but comes with the following restrictions:
>
> - Data is restricted to sandbox users and the 20 most recent media from each sandbox user
> - Reduced API rate limits

Comment: Thank you, it helped out...I am able to get results for the image which i have posted on Instagram